# Getting error in Xcode when doing this if let objects = objects as? [PFObject]

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Just upgraded to Swift 2 and using Xcode 7. Using Parse for backend.

I'm doing a normal query in background:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "User")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

    }
}
```

I get error in Xcode:

```
Downcast from '[PFObject]?' to '[PFObject]' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove as? [PFObject]

Parse Change the [AnyObject] to a [PFObject]

```
findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({(objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?)
```

so :

```
findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error)
```

The Downcast is not required

Comment: I did this, and it is not fixing the problem. It also states `Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled` on the same line as the Downcast error line. Anyone know the fix?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code into:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "User");

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

   if let objects = objects as! [PFObject] {

   }
}
```